# Failed to connect to MySQL: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am deploying a Wordpress enviroment, and there seems to happen a weird situation.

I did some tweakings and set a new root password like this

```
mysql -u root –p
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
service mysql restart
ufw allow 3306
```

then I changed the settings of `bind` from `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` to from `127.0.0.1` to  `0.0.0.0` so that I can access it via mySQL Workbench. Which was successful as I now am able to enter the DB from outside sources.

Once I changed the password, I altered the `wp-config.php` file and set the new credentials.

[image]

However, now, I am getting errors inside the WordPress whenever I log on, I see the following errors, despite the fact that the website runs without any issues and the articles appear.

```
 Failed to connect to MySQL: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Below is an image of the error I am getting

[image]

I tried manny different scenarios on SO, and I am really sorry in advance for posting this again, but non of the solutions provided work.

Any ideas on resolving this?

And while we are at it,

1. what does `(using password: YES)` or `(using password: NO)` mean ?
2. What is the difference between `root@localhost` and `root@127.0.0.1`

Comment: Seems odd that you'd have to manually grant all privileges to the root account.

Comment: Does WP know you changed the password? You set a new pw, but you never mentioned that you changed the wp_config file.

Comment: @amflare yes, I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

using password: YES shows that you entered mysql password.

127.0.0.1 and localhost are same

Answer (score 0):

Look like you forget to change db connection setting in wp-config.php

```
/** MySql database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'MyNewPass');
```

Comment: I did that, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

using password: YES
means that you have used a password to make a connection to your server.

localhost is a hostname that means this computer and 127.0.0.1 is its IP address so they are the same.

After all here you have set a password for root user and gave it privilege to connect to the server from any host.

I think you should set your new password inside wp-config.php

**EDIT:**
Check your your credentials inside ***wp-config.php***:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'your_db');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'this-is-your-password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // Exactly localhost
```

Comment: @tony9099 Is the MySQL on the same machine with your website? Is it possible to connect to it via mysql -uroot -p?

Comment: yes, they are on the same machine, and yes I can connect via mysql -u root -p

Comment: it is already there and still not working :/

Comment: I just retested, I can login using mysql -u root -p and I do get the `mysql>
` prompt on putty, and I put the exact password in the config file, but I get that error. weird.

Comment: @tony9099 Can you connect with both of `mysql -u root -p -h localhost` and `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147348/discussion-between-tony9099-and-mahyar-damavand).